# Explode each row into multiple rows by splitting a column of a given computed range

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, vlookup, google-query-language, textjoin

I was recently tasked with 'exploding' each row in a given range with respect to the split value of one of the columns, i.e. going from

| Name | Interests | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | swimming, movies | 31 |
| Mary | basketball | 26 |
| Richard | football, music | 21 |

to:

| Name | Interest | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | swimming | 31 |
| John | movies | 31 |
| Mary | basketball | 26 |
| Richard | football | 21 |
| Richard | music | 21 |

It's a little similar to a Cartesian product, only one of the terms needs to be computed on the basis of the value in the *Interests* column. I eventually solved it using an Apps Script function, but I'm wondering if it could be easily solved using a regular formula.

Note that the input range in my case was a product of another formula (a `QUERY(...)`, to be exact), so not necessarily contiguous or addressable within the spreadsheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: this is a very common quesiton.  See this reddit post of mine.
https://www.reddit.com/r/sheets/comments/rrdpoy/a_journey_from_flatten_to_unpivot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A1:A&"×"&SPLIT(B1:B, ", ", )&"×"&C1:C), "×"),
 "where Col3 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: I was about to comment that I couldn't quite accept this answer, because my range was not addressable column by column, as mentioned in the question. But then I realized I can apply your approach first, and *then* wrap the result in `QUERY()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom "UNPIVOT" function [found on this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yJbz8QHFUVa19AzVmk9zL5wUI2h-cX7pgjYSiI7HwNA/edit#gid=725387796). File>Make a Copy to grab the script.  [Also here on github.](https://github.com/MattyPKing/gas/blob/main/unpivot)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNPIVOT(A2:A,"V",SPLIT(B2:B,", ",0),"B",C2:C,"V"))
```

You would then QUERY() the output to eliminate the rows where there was nothing in the second column.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I can also just build a new array manually inside an external function, which is pretty straightforward. The whole point was to avoid external dependencies, though

Comment: @crizzis ok, did you see how I did it with stock funcitons on that same sheet? It's basically what player0 wrote.