# Issue when applying Query and Sumproduct with different array sizes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to apply a mixed formula with `SUMPRODUCT` and `QUERY` to extrapolate some value.

Explaining it better: I have a list of shipments, each of these shipment have listed different merchandise formatted in the adjacent cell in the form of "Merch1 Merch2 Merch3"
all separated by a space. The next cell shows the individual value of each merch listed for that specific shipment. (It's an example that doesn't have to make sense for the formula)

From time I had a formula to gather ALL the "shipments" with a query and obtain the TOTAL value of the singular merch (not the average) with this

```
QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(B2:B)," "))),"Select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null AND Col1 <> '#VALUE!' group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label Col1 'Word'")
```

FLATTEN-SPLIT-FLATTEN is needed to separate the merchs by spaces and then gather them in one single column, which I then use with query to count the singular values and then apply the necessary formulas.

Since the merch is often not ordered (and `SEARCH` just select the first occurrence) and they're often mixed in one single cell (and `MATCH` wouldn't work) I had to search online for a rudimental solution, this formula

```
SUMPRODUCT((IF(ISNUMBER((LEN(" "&$B$2:B&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" "&$B$2:B&" "," "&M2&" ","")))/LEN(" "&M2&" ")),(LEN(" "&$B$2:B&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" "&$B$2:B&" "," "&M2&" ","")))/LEN(" "&M2&" "),0)),IF(ISNUMBER($C$2:C),$C$2:C))
```

Where `M2` is just the merch resulted by the query.
This formula is supposed to count how many of the word "Merch1" (etc.) is contained in the shipment list, and then multiply that by the value.

Now, I'm trying to do something similar but with smaller samples (pretty much other shipments, with the same format, and know the "value" of them)

Showing a test [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jdK2uIVDCTkuU3Mx5gMyMyOacMveAi-BKZOhqNcHQY4/edit#gid=0)

I managed to flatten the list of the sample shipments with two different formulas

```
ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(F2:F3)," ")),"select * where Col1 is not null"))
```

or

```
FILTER(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(F2:F3)," ")),NOT(ISBLANK(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(F2:F3)," ")))))
```

and then use the convoluted `SUMPRODUCT` and `SUBSTITUTE` to obtain the value, but I would like to merge the two formulas, but obviously the array mismatch and it doesn't work as intended

To be honest I think that my last resort would be creating some sort of script on GS and continue with that.

Appreciate all the help anyone can give me.

Comment: the spreadsheet is private.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, changed it to public

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula in Cell E1 in the example below.
`=query({INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A1:A&"×"&SPLIT(B1:B, " ", )&"×"&C1:C), "×"), "where Col3 is not null"))},"select Col2, count(Col2), sum(Col3) group by Col2 order by count(Col2) desc label Col2 'Word', count(Col2) 'Count', sum(Col3) 'Coeff'")`

---

**EXAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]

---

based on @player0 answer in [Explode each row into multiple rows by splitting a column of a given computed range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71386036/1330560)

---

**I just want to have result for "Merch1, Merch2 and Merch3"**

`=query({INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A1:A&"×"&SPLIT(B1:B, " ", )&"×"&C1:C), "×"), "where Col3 is not null"))},"select Col2, count(Col2), sum(Col3) WHERE Col2 MATCHES '(" & JOIN("|", I2:I4) & ")'  group by Col2 order by count(Col2) desc label Col2 'Word', count(Col2) 'Count', sum(Col3) 'Coeff'")`

---

[image: snapshot2]

Comment: Okay, that formula definitely helped remove that huge amount of `SUBSTITUTE` and `LEN` I had before. The issue remain, since I still need to limit the results, using a second list (so `limit by x` would not work) which has a different array size and I cannot use that in the same query. In the example you've given, I just want to have result for "Merch1, Merch2 and Merch3" (which are totally random and not alphabetical) excluding the other two "Merch5 and Merch6".

Comment: "I just want to have result for "Merch1, Merch2 and Merch3". I might have missed something but I can't see where this is described as the required outcome in your question nor in your spreadsheet.

Comment: "I just want to have result for "Merch1, Merch2 and Merch3". - Refer the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, the second answer was useful, with a tweak I succeeded to make it work.
When I said "I would like to merge the two formulas, but obviously the array mismatch and it doesn't work as intended" I meant that I wanted to merge the entire query (with Subs and Len) with the second one obtaining the smaller "shipment" size (In the answer is the 3rd and 4th code). On the document I highlighted in red which final result I was trying to obtain, and the use of `MATCHES` and `JOIN` is brilliant, and exactly what I needed. I was just trying to obtain a way to the solution, not the solution itself.